# Change ul element's width of select2-multiple component

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've simple select 2 component.

```
<select name="Icecream Flavours" class="mydropdown" id="mydd" style="width:250px;" multiple = "multiple"></select>
```

This is a multiple select. If we run the code `$("#mydd").select2();` we will that an `ul` element is added inside the select2 structure with class "select2-selection__rendered".

For some reason I'm trying to change the width of this component. I've tried

```
.select2-selection__rendered{width: 500px;}
.select2-container--default .select2-selection--multiple .select2-selection__rendered {width: 500px;}
.select2-container .select2-selection--multiple .select2-selection__rendere{width: 500px;}
```

Nothing seems to be working.

Through script i can override. But I wanna do through css to maintain cleaner code. what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Check to see how Select2 is applying the width. If it is copying the same inline style via HTML style attribute to the rendered `.select2-selection__rendered` element, then you simply won't be able to override it with CSS selectors. Look at your computed styles in a web inspector to find out how the values are being applied.

There are many articles about CSS style computation rules & precedence of inline styles, selector specificity, etc. This is a pretty straightforward read: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/#specificity-hierarchy

Essentially, think of it this way:

- There are a few types of selectors: IDs, classes, & elements (pseudo-classes & pseudo-elements exist too, but I'll skip them for brevity; if you want to learn more about them read the article I posted or elsewhere).
- When determining which CSS rule takes precedence, count up the number of each selector type. Then the rule with the most IDs wins; if the number of IDs match, then the rule with the most classes wins; if the number of IDs & the number of classes match, then the rule with the most elements wins.
- Inline styles override other CSS selectors. So if you are setting them within HTML or JS be mindful that you'll be clobbering your CSS elsewhere.
- !important is also a thing you can do, but it is pretty universally considered terrible practice, so I'll skip it.

Answer (score -1):

Got it ..

```
.select2-selection--multiple ul {width: 400px !important;}
```

Comment: This is not a good idea. Using `!important` is typically a symptom of not fully understanding how CSS specificity works. Using `!important` is very consistently considered poor practice & will likely only come back to bite you. Often you will wind up using other `!important` declarations to clobber the prior one. `!important` rules can also be very difficult to debug or adjust once they are in place. Please for the sake of your coworkers or even just future-you, I implore you find another way :)